# Java, Netty: Help Understanding ChannelPipelines and addLast

Tags: java, netty

I am working through [some examples](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html) of using the Netty io server.  I am working on understanding the pipeline construct, and how elements that are added to the pipeline effect each other, and how their order is important in the pipeline.  So far I have created a child handler as follows in my main method

```
serverBootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {   
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline().addLast( ... );
    }
}
```

I want to have a pipeline where one handler generates a long with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and another handler that encodes it as a string in the format provided by the `Date` classes `toString` method.  To that end I started with this:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(
    new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext) {
            byte[] bytes = "Press return to get the time\n".getBytes();
            channelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(
                channelHandlerContext
                    .alloc()
                    .buffer(bytes.length)
                    .writeBytes(bytes));
        }
        @Override
        public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Object object) {
            try {
                ChannelFuture channelFuture = channelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(
                    channelHandlerContext
                        .alloc()
                        .buffer()
                        .writeLong(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                channelFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
            } finally {
                ReferenceCountUtil.release(object);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            channelHandlerContext.close();
        }
    }
);
```

How do I modify this so that an encoder encodes the payload as a date string such as `2014-10-07T18:34:10.897-00:00`? Is this the correct way to think about the pipeline, though a trivial example?

In terms of understanding, [looking at this example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/factorial/FactorialServerInitializer.java), it is unclear how the order of this pipeline is executed.  For example, if I assume they execute in linear order, I would thing some data payload is gzipped and then immediately ungzipped.  What am I missing?

```
    pipeline.addLast(ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
    pipeline.addLast(ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));

    // Add the number codec first,
    pipeline.addLast(new BigIntegerDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new NumberEncoder());

    // and then business logic.
    // Please note we create a handler for every new channel
    // because it has stateful properties.
    pipeline.addLast(new FactorialServerHandler());
```

Update:  I found [this diagram](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) but I am still trying to work out how to coerce the long in the example above to a date on the way back to the client.  How would I do that?